# How to remove only www. part from a url - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url, replace

I want to remove only the `www.` part from the URL in javascript. I have tried using the regex `/^(?:www\.)?/i`:

```
"www.example.com".replace(/^(?:www\.)?/i, "")
```

It works fine for the above example. But it doesn't work for URL starting with protocol like `https://www.example.com`.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
https://www.example.com/   ->   https://example.com/

WWW.example.com/   ->   example.com/
```

Comment: `/(^|(http.?:\/\/))(www\.)/`

Comment: `myUrlLikeString.replace(/^(www\.)|((?<=https?:\/\/)www\.)/, "")` should do you, as long as you [don't need to support Safari or IE](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind). Without lookbehind support, you're better off just pulling the string to bits in code.

Comment: @GrafiCode For `https://www.example.com/` it's returning `example.com/`. While it should be `https://example.com/`

Comment: @spender I do need to support Safari browser.

Comment: @Hanzla In which case, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go **:**

```js
const str = 'https://www.example.com';

const res = str.match(/^(http(s)?:(\/\/)www\.|www\.)(.*)/);

console.log(res[res.length - 1]);
```

`RegEx` explanation **:**

- `^` -> start with
- `(http(s)?:(\/\/)www\.` -> match the starting of the string which should contain either `https://www.` or `http://www.`
- `|` -> denotes or
- `www\.` -> match the starting of the string which should contain `www.`
- (.*) ==> use parenthese to capture a group, `.` match anything, `*` 0 or `n` times

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to remove all instances of www, no matter where it appears**

```
/www/.replace('')
```

**If you explicitly want to ensure you are only removing 'www' when it comes after //**

```
/(\/\/)www/.replace('$1')
```

**just replace www if it comes before DOT**

```
/www(\.)/.replace('$1')
```

**Safest: To be sure you aren't remove www if it happens to sit in the querystring or hash**

**Caters for**

- www.
- http://www.
- //www.

```
/^([^:\.]*)(\:\/\/)?www(\.)/.replace('$1$2$3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that should do the trick:

```js
function stripWww(s) {
  // 3 capturing groups
  const regExp = /^(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(.*)/;
  const regExpArr = regExp.exec(s);
  // if no match, just return what was supplied
  if (!regExpArr) return s;
  // otherwise, compose a new string using groups 1 & 3
  // and omitting group 2 ("www.")
  // if "http://" or "https://" is not present,
  // group 1 will be undefined.
  return `${regExpArr[1] ?? ""}${regExpArr[3]}`
}

const data = [
  "http://www.example.com", 
  "https://www.example.com", 
  "www.example.com", 
  "example.com",
  "http://example.com"
];

console.log(data.map(stripWww))
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace keyword and fill with blanks.

Example:

```
const urlMain = "https://www.example.com";
const endUrl = urlMain.replace("www.","");
console.log("Main Url",urlMain);
console.log("End Url",endUrl);
```

Comment: this won't work for `https://mysitewww.com/`

Comment: the specific question is remove "www."

Comment: O.P. obviously needs `www.` to be removed only when it's prepended to the domain. Regex is needed.